# ¿Cómo calcular frecuencias absolutas?

Tags: r

tengo la siguiente tabla en un excel (imagen), es una tabla de frecuencias acumuladas y a partir de ella tengo que sacar las frecuencias relativas totales, por filas y por columnas. Pero no deja de salirme este error y no se como solucionarlo:

> **Error in margin.table(x, margin) : 'x' is not an array**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
attach(evaluaciontrabajadores)

relativastotales <- prop.table(evaluaciontrabajadores)
relativastotales

relativasfila <- prop.table(evaluaciontrabajadores, 1)
relativasfila
```

El error me da al ejecutar **relativasfila**

```
> str(evaluaciontrabajadores)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Mal        : num  0 150
 $ Regular    : num  50 100
 $ Bien       : num  30 40
 $ Sin evaluar: num  20 10
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir la salida de `str(evaluaciontrabajadores)`?

Comment: Bienvenido Gorka a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prop.table()` esta esperando un `array` que no es más que una generalización de una matriz, por lo que podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
prop.table(as.matrix(evaluaciontrabajadores), 1)
```

Es decir, convertimos el `data.frame` original en una matriz con `as.matrix()` y luego si podremos usar `prop.table()`